# Store image url and display it for user profile

Tags: php

When I click on edit an image button I get this in a dialog:

```
   <form method="POST" action="getdata.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="myimage">
 <input type="submit" name="submit_image" value="Upload">
</form>
```

How can I save the picture url that the user uploaded into the database and have display from now on. I just want to know if Im suppose to store it anywhere like a variable or is this even the right first step?

Comment: your code (php) is failing on a few levels, if that's your actual code and not just pseudo. Error reporting and check your console.

Comment: I editted it, I just dont know hwo to get the details and store it, I have a variable in my database called "image"; datatype blob , am i suppose to make more than one? @Fred-ii-